# What is the meaning of errors 30 / 300 when casting using Google Cast?

Tags: android, ios, chromecast, google-cast

I'm trying to cast HLS from iPhone / Android app to Chromecast, but am repeatedly getting errors.

On the iOS side:
com.google.cast.GCKError Code=30 "Media failed to load"
gck_detailed_error_code=300

I have been suspecting CORS issues and have tried a few things on and off, like setting `Access-Control-Request-Origin *` on the serving end, despite this I still get error 30/300 in some environments (but not in others). It would help to know what 30/300 means, but I haven't found any documentation on this, like on this page: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/error_codes

Comment: i am not sure.. but does this helps? https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/g_c_k_error_8h#aea7a716be62f301015e255e1ba63a9cc

Comment: it says `GCKErrorCodeMediaLoadFailed = 30`

Comment: Yes, true I've found the meaning of `30`. Still looking for `300`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [link](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver/error_codes) to all their error codes

NETWORK_UNKNOWN 300 Encountered a generic network error when fetching a resource not covered within the range [301-399] Developers must ensure that the content being fetched is accessible and the server's response is formed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Same error my app.

When i play .m3u8 formate(url) in chromecast via iOS app.
Chromecast not support this kind of formate.

Refer link: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media#image-formats